# Firemonkey: TSpeedButton IsPressed no visible Effect?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

How do I set a TSpeedButton (on a TToolbar) to look pressed down? It's only highlighted when clicking but gets normal when the mouse leaves it. I set the property Stayspressed to True and indeed the property IsPressed becomes and stays True, but this state is not visible.

Answer (score 3):

What style are you using? Some of the included ones do not have every effect included.

First, revert back to the windows style. If that works, then it's definitely a styling issue, rather than a code issue.

If you want to add an effect (actually an animation) to another style:

- Right click on a button and select Edit Default Style.
- Find the Fill.Color property of the Rectangle you want to show the anmimation.
- Click the animation icon and add a TColorAnimation
- Set: the StartValue (the existing value).
- The StopValue
- The Trigger: IsPressed=True
- Repeat the above to add a second animation with the Start and StopValues reversed and Trigger of IsPressed=False

Comment: I checked the default stylebook for TSpeedButton. It is there, but it's buggy. There are two triggers fighting each other and the one for IsPressed always looses.

Comment: If you don't want to say which style you're using that's okay, but without that info it's not easy to help.

Comment: It's the "Windows Style"...the default one. I didn't set any style explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one - the standard TButton style includes effects which work - the button will look pressed when "IsPressed" is true.  However, other styles (and especially your own) can be much more problematic.  I have found the best solution is to have 2 styles and change the style when the button is pressed.

I found it pretty impossible to get "mouseover" animation to work with "pressed" animation in buttons - normally you want to highlight the button slightly when the mouse passes over and then add an effect when you press - especially when you don't want the default shadow effect but a colour effect (which I prefer, I don't like the inner shadow effect of a default button press), but I always seemed to end up with issues. Either one effect wouldn't fire OR the button state wouldn't return to what you'd expect (visually I mean).

My advice - add a little bit of extra code to change the style for the pressed button, you might go mad otherwise :-)